# Como fazer LogOff com Ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Eu tenho meu menu, e ele tem um `dropdown`

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Usuário</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="/">Meus dados</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="LogOff">Sair</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Eu tentei usar dessa forma o "Sair"

```
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm"}))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

    <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Sair</a></li>
</ul>
}
```

Mas ele quebra com o menu por renderizar um `Form`

Tentei então com Ajax

```
$("#LogOff").on("click", function (e) {
    $.post('@Url.Content("~/Account/LogOff")');
});
```

Assim ele manda o Post, mas tenho que dar "Refresh" ir para o login, ignorando o `RedirectToAction` que está na action `LogOff` e também não aceita o `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect não vai funcionar para requisições ajax. Você tem que separar em duas partes.

Ex:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#logoutForm").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $.post('@Url.Content("~/Account/LogOff")', null, function(){
                window.location = '/Account/Login';
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```